# position jsqmessage bubble

Tags: ios, swift, chat, jsqmessagesviewcontroller

i've a problem with the position of my JSQmessage bubble.

when i "send" it the position is good but when i change the view then come back the bubble is more at left than before.
(if i send a new one all bubble come back to a good position).

can someone now what can happen?

**bubble at wrong position**

[image]

**bubble at good position (after new send)**

[image]

Comment: Are you using constraint to adjust position?

Comment: no my Coversationviewcontrolleur inherit from JSQMessagesViewController   and the addition of cell in the view is done in the code nothing is done in the storyboard view

Comment: I have the same issue. I am also wondering if there is a way to change message position.

Answer (score 1):

In your `ViewDidLoad()` this

```
viewDidLoad(){
    super.viewDidLoad()
    collectionView?.collectionViewLayout.incomingAvatarViewSize = .zero
    collectionView?.collectionViewLayout.outgoingAvatarViewSize = .zero
}
```

I also have this function but I would assume essentially the same thing.

```
override func collectionView(collectionView: JSQMessagesCollectionView!, avatarImageDataForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) -> JSQMessageAvatarImageDataSource? {
    return nil
}
```

Comment: This partially worked for me. Whenever I re-open a conversation that has at least one message, sent/received message have a huge padding from the border of the screen. The are nearly positioned in the middle of the screen.

Answer (score 0):

Use this after you load your chat history:

```
 dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    [self.collectionView reloadData];
});
```

This code is in objective c but I am sure you can convert it to swift :)